# Modules and binaries not found in Docker container

Tags: docker, cmake

I am trying to set up a Docker container with some of my own code. It is some Fortran code that does some calculations on data from grib files. That is not a problem. A dependency is [eccodes](https://confluence.ecmwf.int//display/ECC/ecCodes+installation) which I need to compile in my Docker container. It compiles nicely when I build the container, but I have no idea where the modules are. They are not in the usual /usr/local.

I have searched for some binaries when building the container by looking for "grib_dump", which is one executable from eccodes, but with no luck.

I am using this Dockerfile. I do not have much experience with Docker, so maybe I violate some best practices.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential cmake wget

# HDF5
RUN apt-get -y install libhdf5-serial-dev

# NetCDF4
RUN apt-get -y install libnetcdf-dev

# gfortran
RUN apt-get -y install gfortran

RUN wget https://confluence.ecmwf.int/download/attachments/45757960/eccodes-2.13.1-Source.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf eccodes-2.13.1-Source.tar.gz
ENV ECCODES_DIR /usr/local
RUN mkdir ecbuild && cd ecbuild && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ECCODES_DIR ../eccodes-2.13.1-Source

RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
# pip
RUN pip3 install schedule
RUN pip3 install netCDF4
RUN pip3 install f90nml

RUN ls $ECCODES_DIR
RUN grib_dump

WORKDIR /kfapp
COPY . /kfapp

RUN make
```

When I run:

```
RUN ls $ECCODES_DIR
RUN grib_dump
```

there is nothing in $ECCODES_DIR and grib_dump is not found. I need to link the module files from eccodes, but I have no idea where to find them, when they are not in $ECCODES_DIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find your build files in `/ecbuild`
you do not find anything in `/usr/local` because you do not run `make` and `make install` after your `cmake` command

here an example from the [Docs](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+installation):

```
> tar -xzf  eccodes-x.y.z-Source.tar.gz
> mkdir build ; cd build

> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/you/install/eccodes ../eccodes-x.y.z-Source
...

> make
> ctest
> make install
```

PS: you do not need also to set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` because the `/usr/local` is the default

Comment: I was not aware that it is possible to set ARG instead of ENV. I like to set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX always, so I can always see it directly. I completely forgot about the make and make install for some reason. That certainly did the trick!

Comment: yes , `ARG` is helpful for using Variables in Build stage